# LWC lightning-datatable ignores time-zone for Time (not Datetime) data

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, time

Unlike Date and Datetime fields, Time fields are displayed and stored in UTC (there is no user locale adjustment.  The problem is that the LWC lightning-datatable ignores the time-zone typeattribute for Time fields (it works OK for Datetime fields).

This is a Time field -- not Datetime, not Date.  Time.  The lightning-datatable column definition is type="date" in order to display the format specified in the typeattributes.  However, the time-zone and time-zone-name attributes are ignored for Time fields and the value is always displayed offset by the current user's locale (which makes this different than everywhere else in the SF UI)

Short of creating a fake column in my datatable, then overriding the field on Edit, does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Datetime is stored in UTC and converted to contextual user timezone when displayed. Date and Time are timezoneless (so can be considered "local", despite the fact that Salesforce renders a zulu symbol for the time when converted to string). That is why the conversion is ignored, because it is not relevant. This is entirely consisted. Only Datetime is timezone converted. The others never are. Note, however, that Date is implicitly converted to Datetime as UTC midnight when used where a Datetime is expected.

Comment: That is how I want it to work, but it doesn't work that way for Time fields.  The Time field is stored and displayed in the SF UI as UTC EXCEPT in  lightning-datatable lwc component in which it IS timezone adjusted.

Comment: I solved my immediate problem by creating an extra datatable column and adding back in the timezone offset to the value from the Time field to display in the extra field.    If the lightning-datatable component is ever updated to properly handle Time fields, I can just remove the extra javascript processing in the wire return function.

Comment: I have not seen the behaviour you report. Please [edit] the question to add the technical detail (code snippets) for your data table and the time field.

Comment: Thx.  I will update this question when I get to a computer later today.  Meanwhile here is another post that shows exactly the same problem.   https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308429/time-conversion-lwc-datatable-apex

Comment: So the problem is using the wrong type. A time is not a date or date/time value. As is mentioned in Salesforce documentation, the support for Time is very limited and indeed broken in some contexts (such as in lightning-record-form). I recommend you switch to using a formatted string input and deal with the conversion yourself.

Comment: Agreed Time support is limited.   Time works perfectly in every other lwc component I've tried other than the lightning-datatable.  The fake table column I have implemented simply adjusts the Time value based on the timezone offset (adds if western, subtracts if eastern) and everything works fine.

Comment: Try lightning-record-form or lightning-edit-record-form - they don't work with Time. I raised this with Saleforce 18 months or more ago and they said they don't support Time as a data type in their LWC infrastructure. I recommend the solution I gave above.

Comment: Using the fake column in the table lets the column be sorted so it is working exactly as I need it. Thanks for your help confirming there wasn't an easier solution (yet :))